# AlarmManager blocked when device is in IDLE state

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I read many topics about this and no one was helpful .
so when I schedule the alarm for more than 30min later and i put the phone somewhere the alarm does not work on time, but it works when I turn on the device , I found that the problem is the alarm manager being blocked when the device is in idle 
I tried a wakeLock but without any result

I'm using

```
alarmManger.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi)
```

how can i make the alarm works even in idle state

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`
like `alarmManger.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi)` .

And also check battery otpimisation setting is off for your app so that android custom ROM by devices will not kill background services for battery saving purpose.

Comment: how can i make this works for api>=16 how can i make it works on all devices ? there is a lot of problems with this

Comment: You have to use condition while setting alarm for example
`if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
}else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
    }`

Also have look at below link for other use cases of doze-standby mode
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: i did something deferent than this and it worked 
thanks

Comment: @Sohaib Please share you solution it might be useful for others too

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code worked fine :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi);}
            else { 
                   alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi);}

   }else {


            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi);
        }
```